# Magento 2 how to pass query string to checkout js files

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, querystring

I'm using magento 2. I need to add some string query in the checkout all .js files.

> ex -
>   http://127.0.0.1/Magento-CE-2.1.6/pub/static/version1498714113/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information.js?ver1.0

i need to add **?ver1.0** last string in the above url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spent some times i found the setting is available in Magento Admin under

> System-> Configuration-> Advanced-> Developer-> Static Files Settings-> Sign Static Files => Yes.

Ref - http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/static-file-signature.html

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/architecture/view/static-process.html?_ga=2.137738291.2036548680.1499761849-1530600774.1490772284